# MainActor vs MainActor(unsafe)

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

We can create a `@MainActor` `Task` like this:

```
Task { @MainActor in
    print("hi")
}
```

But also with `@MainActor(unsafe)` like this:

```
Task { @MainActor(unsafe) in
    print("hi")
}
```

What's the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main purpose of `@MainActor(unsafe)` is to make incremental adoption of concurrency easier. You can read this in detail explained in the [proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/concurrency-in-swift-5-and-6/49337). If you mark your type as `@MainActor(unsafe)` if you try to access properties and methods synchronously in code that hasn't adopted `async/await` without breaking anything.

For example following code won't compile with only `@MainActor` as here actor isolated property accessed from synchronous context:

```swift
@MainActor
class SomeViewModel {
    let value1 = 0
    var value2 = 0
    func getValue2() -> Int { value2 }
    func setValue2(_ newValue: Int) { value2 = newValue }
}

func doSomething(with viewModel: SomeViewModel) {
    _ = viewModel.value1
    _ = viewModel.value2 // ERROR: Property 'value2' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not be referenced from this synchronous context
    _ = viewModel.getValue2() // ERROR: Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'getValue2()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
    viewModel.setValue2(3) // ERROR: Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'setValue2' in a synchronous nonisolated context
}
```

But if you change `@MainActor` to `@MainActor(unsafe)` there are no more build errors. Note that `@MainActor(unsafe)` is only applicable to swift 5 code to make incremental adoption of concurrency easier and in swift 6 it won't have any effect and would behave the same as `@MainActor`.

Also `@MainActor(unsafe)` is interchangeable with `@preconcurrency @MainActor`. You also can use `-warn-concurrency` compiler option to get all the errors that you would get with only `@MainActor` as warnings.